# combine dataframes with similar column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have multiple dataframes that have the same metrics data in their columns, except the column names in each dataframe is different. For example:

DataFrame A columns: `date`, `command_83`, `state_83`

DataFrame B columns: `date`, `commands_52`, `state_52`

Dataframe C columns: `date`, `command_67`, `state_67`

Is there a way for me to combine these dataframes together such that the resultant dataframe has columns: `date`, `command`, `state`? And it has added B's data below A, and C's data below B.

Comment: for each df: `df.columns = ['date', 'command', 'state']`, then `pd.concat()` these 3 dfs

Answer (score 1):

You could rename the columns so that all the dataframes will have the same column names, then use `pd.concat()` with default `axis=0` to stack them vertically

```
dfA.columns = ['date', 'command', 'state']
dfB.columns = ['date', 'command', 'state']
dfC.columns = ['date', 'command', 'state']

df = pd.concat([dfA, dfB, dfC])
```